# Finding hyperlinks inside a PDF document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm currently using Aspose PDF Kit to split a 'master PDF' up into individual documents + thumbnails.  This works well at the moment, but the device I'll be rendering the PDF on won't know about the annotations/links within the PDF.

I understand there is a way to parse the PDF document to detect the X/Y position of a hyperlink etc, is there an simple way to extract/iterate across the document data so I can write it to an external XML file?

Comment: Try http://www.pdfsharp.net/ - it can add links, maybe you can extract them as well (haven't tried)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try [Docotic.Pdf](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) library for this (disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle).

The library can be used to retrieve all hyperlinks in a document. You may retrieve bounding box, text and other properties of a link, too.

Please take a look at "[Extract text from link target](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/TextFromLink)" sample. It may help you to get started.